AWS Lambda doesn't seem to run axios get request
I'm using AWS Lambda to run this function, but it doesn't seem to work. I cant seem to get why the axios get request or any get request from a website isn't working.
// Import the required libraries
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const OpenAI = require('openai');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const axios = require('axios');

dotenv.config();

// Initialize the Express application
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

// Use body-parser to parse JSON request bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Initialize the OpenAI client
const client = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

// In-memory store for conversations
const conversations = {};
conversations['user'] = [];

// Fetch content from michaelani.com and its subpages
const initializeWebsiteContent = async () => {
    try {
        const homeContent = await axios.get('https://r.jina.ai/https://michaelani.com/');
        const bioContent = await axios.get('https://r.jina.ai/https://michaelani.com/Autobiography');
        const hobbContent = await axios.get('https://r.jina.ai/https://michaelani.com/Hobbies');
        conversations['user'].push({ role: 'system', content: homeContent.data });
        conversations['user'].push({ role: 'system', content: bioContent.data });
        conversations['user'].push({ role: 'system', content: hobbContent.data });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error initializing website content: ${error.message}`);
    }
};

fs.readFile(__dirname + '/mike_prompt.txt', async (err, data) => {

   if (err)
       throw err;
   const mike_prompt = data.toString();
   conversations['user'].push({ role: 'system', content: mike_prompt });

    await initializeWebsiteContent();
});

// Define a POST route for the chatbot
app.post('/chat', async (req, res) => {
   const { sender, message } = req.body; // Extract the message from the request body
    
    if (!sender || !message) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User ID and message are required' });
    }
   
    conversations[sender].push({ role: 'user', content: message });

    try {
        // Send the message to OpenAI and get the response
        const response = await client.chat.completions.create({
            messages: conversations[sender],
            model: "gpt-4o",
        });

        const responseString = response.choices[0].message.content;
       conversations[sender].push({ role: 'assistant', content: responseString });

        console.log(responseString);

        // Send the chatbot's reply back to the client
        res.json({ reply: responseString });

    } catch (error) {
        // Handle any errors that occur
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});

// Export the app for Lambda
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);

I tried running it and it seems to keep resulting in this
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "headers": {
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "content-security-policy": "default-src 'none'",
    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
    "content-type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "content-length": "139"
  },
  "isBase64Encoded": false,
  "body": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot GET /</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n"
}

AWS Lambda doesn't count it as an error, so I get a success, but this isn't the desired result

How did you run "this function"?

I was trying it using a test case {system: user, message: hello}
It seems that all I needed to do was run the code from an API Gateway and reformat the JSON
